# ASP.NET MVC3 Linking Area "Resource cannot be found"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, hyperlink, area

I just barely created a new Area to organize my code.
But currently I am having trouble actually linking it from my "base" or "root" index page, to my new area page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Tube Record Form", "BearingAssemblyForm", "_HiCT", new { area = "HICT" }, null)
```

---

```
 public class HICTAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "HICT";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "HICT_default",
            "HICT/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "_HiCT", action = "BearingAssemblyForm", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The resource cannot be found. 
And it seems its linked wrongly

> Requested URL: /HICT/HiCT/BearingAssemblyForm
>    
>  Controller: HiCT,
>   View/Action: BearingAssemblyForm, Area: HICT.

How would I like this? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Pls look this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554561/troubleshooting-the-resource-cannot-be-found-error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554561/troubleshooting-the-resource-cannot-be-found-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText",
        "ActionName",
        "ControllerName",
        new { area = "HICT" }, null)
```

I think you're not using the correct `@Html.ActionLink` method overload.

First off all, see if your area is registered correctly:

```
public class Routes : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "HICT";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "HICT_default",
            "HICT/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "_HiCT", action = "BearingAssemblyForm", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Make sure you're calling `RegisterAllAreas` inside the `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Okay I switch it to @Html.ActionLink("Tube Record Form", "BearingAssemblyForm", "HiCT", new { area = "HICT" }, null). I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: So you have a controller with the same name... Change your controller name and try it again.

Comment: What do you mean my controller is the same name? The same name as my Area? Thanks!

Comment: Yes... try giving your controller a different name and test again.

Comment: Yup i'm still getting the same problem:
Now I have    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tube Record Form", "BearingAssemblyForm", "_HiCT", new { area = "HICT" }, null)</li>

Comment: Yes I did, check my edit I did above, I posted what I have. thanks again

Comment: So, your controller is named `_HiCTController`?

Comment: What happens when you navigate to /HICT/_HiCT/BearingAssemblyForm in your browser? Does the action method gets called?

Comment: No the action method does not end up getting called. I'm still getting "The resource cannot be found".

Comment: Yeah : http://localhost:53655/HICT/_HiCT/BearingAssemblyForm, does not get called >_<, so what is wrong with my area route not getting registered? Thank you so much for your help btw.

Comment: See... it should be in this format: `localhost:####/HICT/_HiCT/BearingAssemblyForm` where #### is the port number you have while debugging the app. If it does not get called then your area route is not being registered. Place a breakpoint inside the action method `BearingAssemblyForm`and see if the app stops there. If it stops there and you get the resource cannot be found chances are your view is not inside the correct folder. It should be placed here: `Areas\HICT\Views\_HiCT\BearingAssemblyForm.cshtml` Remember that you changed the controller name. You must rename the folder accordingly.

Comment: Yeah its not getting called at all. Wait.. my views is right now Areas/HICT/Views/BeaingAssmblyForm.cshtml

Comment: So... it's probably the PROBLEM! :) See the structure must match as I described in the comment above.

Comment: Wait.. I'm kinda confused on ASP.net MVC3 structures haha. So I thought the _HiCT was just a controller, I need to actually have a folder for it?

Comment: Yeahh... Instead of `Areas\HICT\Views\BearingAssmblyForm.cshtml ` you must have: `Areas\HICT\Views\_HiCT\BearingAssemblyForm.cshtml`.

Comment: Okay so I have changed it to Areas\HICT\Views\_HiCT\BearingAssemblyForm.cshtml. But i'm still getting. Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /HICT

Comment: Does it have to do with something with the Requested URL: /HICT?

Comment: No... the folder structure you created is still wrong... see my comment above. It must be: `Areas\HICT\Views\_HiCT\BearingAssemblyForm.cshtml`

Comment: Well... now I have no idea what's going on. If the breakpoint does not get hit, seems the route is not being registered at all.

Comment: I am calling the @Html.ActionLink from my "Master" page view and not on a _layout, that shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: I don't think it would cause this error... As a last attempt: rename you controller to something different: `Test` for example. Get rid of that `_`underscore.

Comment: Yeah I changed it to `TestController`, still the same thing. I think it has something to not even finding the controller and the register stuff like you said x.x.

Comment: Remember to rename the view folder to Test too! :) If it doesn't work at all, start a new fresh project and make some tests...

Comment: Oh right, yup, i've renamed the view folder to `test` too. Still same problem grrr..

Answer (score 0):

/Master/BearingAssemblyForm

usually, Master is the controller and the 2nd part is action, so it seems your controller name is different than your route.

Comment: Yeah I think that is the problem, is there any way I could switch the controller to HiCT instead

Comment: You can try creating a custom route, although it could turn out to be tricky in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

on `Application_Start` in your Global.asax? What server are you using for development Cassini, IISExpress, IIS?

Edit after reviewing more detailed information.

In your Admin Area Registration File if you have this code

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "CoolProject.Web.Areas.Admin.Contollers" }
);
```

I think there is a typo in `CoolProject.Web.Areas.Admin.Contollers` and it should be `CoolProject.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers`?

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean, but I am calling             AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); in my Globa.asax, would it have to be something to do with my HICTAreaRegistration code?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a wile but this should work.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Tube Record Form", "action", "Area/controller")
```